# 'Inheriting' Show between different defined data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
data Player =         User | COM  deriving Eq
data Spot   = JustA Player | None deriving Eq

instance Show Player where
    show User = "X"
    show COM  = "O"

instance Show Spot where
    show None = " "
```

In the code above I have created two data types, `Player` and `Spot`, which is either `Just Player` or `None`.
Now I would to be able to `show JustA User` to give the result "X", but this does not work. I have tried various methods to use instances but they have not worked for me.

The error that is given is:

```
ghci> tictactoe
The computer will go first as O

   |   |
---+---+---
 *** Exception: tictactoe.hs:11:5-19: Non-exhaustive patterns in function show
```

(where there is an error as it is attempting to `show JustA COM`)

Comment: Like that: `show (JustA player) = show player`.

Answer (score 4):

There's more than one problem.

## Non-exhaustive patterns

The error message `Non-exhaustive patterns in function show` tells you that there's a case you haven't handled.

GHC can tell you that at compile-time (or when loading in GHCi) if you turn on the [incomplete-patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-patterns) flag:

```
ghci> :set -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
```

With that, you'll not only get a warning from GHCi, but it'll also tell you where the problem is:

```
Q77520101.hs:11:5: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `show':
        Patterns of type `Spot' not matched: JustA _
   |
11 |     show None = " "
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Usually, though, it's easier to just turn on a wider set of flags that include `incomplete-patterns`: [Wall](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wall).

To address that problem, add the missing case to `Spot`'s `show` instance:

```
instance Show Spot where
    show None = " "
    show (JustA p) = "JustA " ++ show p
```

All that said, however, it's easier to just let the compiler derive the `show` instance:

```
data Player =         User | COM  deriving (Eq, Show)
data Spot   = JustA Player | None deriving (Eq, Show)
```

although, granted, that doesn't give you quite the same output. With that alternative, `show User` will return `User` instead of `X`. That is, however, considered idiomatic.

## Syntax

Another problem may relate to the expression `show JustA User`. If you try it in GHCi, it'll give you a detailed error message:

```
ghci> show JustA User

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type: Player -> t
                  with actual type: [Char]
    * The function `show' is applied to two value arguments,
        but its type `(Player -> Spot) -> [Char]' has only one
      In the expression: show JustA User
      In an equation for `it': it = show JustA User
    * Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
```

The function `show` expects a *single* input value, but due to Haskell's syntax, an expression like `show JustA User` looks to the Haskell compiler like a function call with two arguments.

You can address that concern in at least two ways:

```
ghci> show (JustA User)
"JustA X"
ghci> show $ JustA User
"JustA X"
```

These two alternatives use different syntax, but they are equivalent. It's a matter of preference whether you use one or the other.

Comment: OP wants "X", not "JustA X".